# What is the definition of love according to Nietzsche?

Tags: terminology, nietzsche

I just read Thus Spoke Zarathustra, and the word love is mentioned many times in the book. Nonetheless, I don't recall an exact definition of what love is, according to the author. Did I miss it, or is it in other books? I'm not an expert and I would like to know a bit more, maybe also where I can read something about the topic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nietzsche is not Spinoza: he does not start from definitions and axioms ...

On *love*, you can see e.g.:

- Robert Solomon, [Living with Nietzsche: What the Great "Immoralist"' Has to Teach Us](https://books.google.it/books?id=hw5jPf_FL4sC&pg=PA89) (2003), **Ch.4 Nietzsche on Resentment, Love, and Pity**, page 89-on.

The author discuss *sexual* love, *spiritual* love developed
through Christianity, often called *agapé* (in Greek) or *caritas* (in Latin), as well as:

> one kind of love that, perhaps, is the truest of the true loves that Nietzsche would defend. That is friendship, *philia*, which may or may not contain an erotic component but in any case represents a kind of ideal of Being-with-Others for Nietzsche.

Answer (score 1):

The following aphorism gets to the heart of the matter if you ignore N's main point re "unegoistic" and if you consider that one may be hollow in some aspects and overfull in others, and one's counterpart the reverse. The result: perfect complementarity.

"Unegoistic!" – This one is hollow and wants to be full, that one is overfull and wants to be emptied – both go in search of an individual who will serve their purpose. And this process, understood in its higher sense is in both cases called by the same name: love – what? Is love supposed to be something unegoistic? [D 145, Cambridge]